# Hibernate locking a arraylist of items

Tags: java, hibernate

```
List <Student> st = session.createQuery ("select ids from students where a = :a")
                        .setString("a", value)
                        .list();

//Errors out saying that ArrayList is an unknown entity
session.lock(st, LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

Students itself extends Serializable.  How do you lock an arraylist of serailizables in Hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

You need to spin through the list and lock the entities one by one.

```
for(Student s : st) {
  session.lock(s, LockMode.UPGRADE);
}
```

NOTE: [Session#lock(java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.LockMode)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#lock%28java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.LockMode%29) is deprecated in favor of session.buildLockRequest(LockMode.UPGRADE).lock(student)

**UPDATE:**
You can also lock directly on the Query via [Query.setLockMode(java.lang.String, org.hibernate.LockMode)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setLockMode%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.LockMode%29).

Comment: Can there be a race condition here, as two threads fired the same query and while iterating one acquired lock on one and the other acquired lock on the other. I wanted to avoid the looping, is firing the query select .. for update the best way then

Comment: @kal Yes, definitely.  Setting the lock mode on the query itself may mitigate that concern, at least as much as possible outside of locking at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPA repository, then you can use the following sample:

```
import com.example.Student;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Lock;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import javax.persistence.LockModeType;
import java.util.List;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Lock(value = LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select s from Student s where s.id IN (:ids)")
    List<Student> findByIdsAndLockForWrite(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);

}
```

Please note that the service that calls this repository should use:
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`